# How to invoke callback from different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, callback

I have a publisher-subscriber pattern where publisher has `subscribeFoo(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)> callback)` that enables subscribers to register callback in the publisher. And save callbacks into a `vector`. Firing callbacks when new `Foo` comes by iterating all callbacks in `vector`. But my question is how to support multithreading? Saying that a subscriber subscribes Foo from a different thread other than publisher's. Then how could I fire that callback from the registered thread? I have no idea how to implement it.

Right now I have `MyPublisher`

```cpp
void MyPublisher::subscribeFoo(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)> callback) {
   callbacks_.push_back(callback);
}

void MyPublisher::notifyAll() {
  auto f = std::make_shared<Foo>();
  for (auto& cb: callbacks_) {
    cb(f);
  }
}
```

However this seems only supports single thread right?

IDEA: In Qt, there is signal-slot mechanism to achieve this. And even when connecting signal and slots it allows different [behaviors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) which allows you to determine the calling behavior.

Comment: If you're using QT, then signals and slots are the answer.  If not, you could use asio (or boost.asio, the non-standalone version), `std::async`, or just maintain your own thread pool.  If you want the callback to run on the same thread that originally registered it, then that thread will need to occasionally poll your publisher to see if new events have arrived.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I like the idea to manage my own thread pool, thanks! But I wonder if polling my publisher would greatly downgrade the performance. Saying I have 10 subscribers and the publisher is publishing data approximately 10 times per second. Then I would have 10 threads keep asking my publisher "is it ready?"  (perhaps more frequently than 10 per secs). The best would be having something like `get_thread(thread_id)->invoke(callback)`

Comment: That's not how threads work.  Threads execute instructions one after another in sequence.  There's no way to asynchronously force one run some piece of code.  UNIX-style OS signals are the closest thing to that, but there's no way to tell the OS which thread to deliver a signal to, and you're severely limited in what you can do in a signal handler.  Even if you maintain your own thread pool, those threads will have to loop and poll some shared callback queue (probably guarded by a condition variable).

Comment: @MilesBudnek Yeah I understand, til now the best way I could think of is still having a simple `notified()` method in subscribers to query new data from my publisher.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an `Subscriber` having method like `SetFoo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr)` and use `std::condition_variable` to notify `Subscriber` object when callback should be called. But other threads will be blocked until condition variable will be notified from publisher thread.

Comment: Previously I just have a `MyPublisher::notify()` method where calling out all my subscribers' `notified()` methods and also a `getFoo()` to let subscribers to retrieve it, and then in `notified()` method, I could retrieve it from my subscriber's thread by direct calling `getFoo()`. But I feel like this is way too clumsy.